# Command Pattern in Ruby

Tags: ruby, design-patterns, solid-principles, command-pattern

I like Ruby and I'm learning design patterns. Here is an example of Command Pattern. The domain model is as follows:

- **Command** - generic interface for all command
- **OnCommand**, **OffCommand** - particular command implementing Command interface, both use TV object as a receiver
- **Button** - uses Command objects to get result
- **RemoteContol** - client, initializes Button and Command objects
  Button - uses Command objects to execute command
- **TV** - receives the commands

Here is some code for this issue:

```
class TV
  def on
    puts 'TV is on'
  end

  def off
    puts 'TV is off'
  end
end

class Command
  class Error < StandardError; end

  def execute
    raise Error
  end
end

class OnCommand < Command
  attr_reader :tv

  def initialize(tv)
    @tv = tv
  end

  def execute
    tv.on
  end
end

class OffCommand < Command
  attr_reader :tv

  def initialize(tv)
    @tv = tv
  end

  def execute
    tv.off
  end
end

class Button
  attr_reader :command

  def initialize(command)
    @command = command
  end

  def execute_command
    command.execute
  end
end

class RemoteControl
  attr_reader :tv

  def initialize(tv)
    @tv = tv
    @buttons = {
      on: Button.new(OnCommand.new(tv)),
      off: Button.new(OffCommand.new(tv))
    }
  end

  def use_button(name)
    button(name).execute_command
  end

  private

  def button(name)
    @buttons.fetch name
  end
end
```

Here is usage example:

```
tv = TV.new                                                                                                             
remote_control = RemoteControl.new(tv)                                                                                  
remote_control.use_button(:on) # TV is on                                                                                         
remote_control.use_button(:off) # TV is off
```

How good have I understood Command Pattern? Is it a good example?

Any thoughts are appreciated

**UPDATED**

I guess replacing **TV** with **InfraredTransmitter** as commands receiver will make the example more appropriate. Because only TV by itself can execute "on" command. And RemoteControl has physical access to its infrared transmitter which is able to send different commands to TV.

Answer (score 1):

`Command` should not have any references to `TV`. Here it’s **not** a command, it’s a **tv-only** command. Here is more rubyish approach:

```
class Command
  def call(*args, &cb)
    target, command, *rest = *args
    target.public_send command, *rest, &cb
  end
end

%i|on off|.each do |command|
  const_set("Command#{command.to_s.capitalize}", Class.new(Command) do
    def call(*args, &cb)
      target, *rest = *args
      super(target, command, *rest, &cb)
    end
  end
end

class Button
  attr_reader :command

  def initialize(command) # accepts :on, "on", CommandOn
    @command = case command
               when Class then command
               when Symbol, String
                 const_get("Command#{command.to_s.capitalize}")
               end.new
  end

  def call(target, *args, &cb)
    command.(target, *args, &cb)
  end
end

class RemoteControl
  def initialize(tv)
    @tv = tv
    @buttons = %i|on off|.map { |c| [c, Button.new(c)] }.to_h
  end
  def call(command)
    @buttons[command].(@tv)
  end
end

remote_control = RemoteControl.new(TV.new)
remote_control.(:on)
remote_control.(:off)
```

With this approach, `Command` might be reused for any other target without a necessity to declare new `Command`. It *must be* target agnostic, otherwise it’s not a generic `Command` pattern.

---

As pointed by @Aetherus, within this approach one does not need a superclass at all here. `Command` above might be safely removed, unless you have some common logic to be put there.

Comment: If a command has only one method, I think I can replace the command instances with procs. A command is good for a suite of interrelated algorithms like doing something and undoing it.

Comment: @Aetherus `Command` pattern is intended to have the single method. Yes, in ruby one might safely use procs instead, and, basically, I do use procs, written with method syntax, there.

Comment: @user3309314 Nah. In constants, for instance.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But so you can't implement unexecute functionality in case.

Comment: @user3309314 You can use hashes that contain 2 procs each to implement undo.

Comment: Yes, it's also possible. I guess however having a generic class or module allows make code more predictable. If there is undo functionality and programmer will forget to implement undo action you can raise a sensible error  for example

Comment: @user3309314 Then a general struct will do the trick. `Command = Struct.new(:execute, :rollback)`, both `execute` and `rollback` are procs.

Comment: @Aetherus Matz wanted to make everything an object. I either use ruby with all the implicit patterns Matz had put into, or switch to Haskell/C when the natural ruby paradigms seem alien for something. Here I would use classes because we are ruby. `Struct`s are in general foreign concept to the whole language and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Look correct to me.
[Command](http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Command/) pattern has following particpants:

**Command** – declares an interface for executing an operation
**ConcreteCommand** – defines a binding between a Receiver object and an action
**Client** – creates a ConcreteCommand object and sets its receiver
**Invoker** – asks the command to carry out the request
**Receiver** – knows how to perform the operations associated with carrying out a request

So, in your example, **Command** is **Command**, **OnCommand**, **OffCommand** are **ConcreteCommand(s)**, **TV** is **Receiver**, **Button** is **Invoker**, **RemoteControl** is **Client**.

Comment: In the OP `Command` declares not an interface for executing an operation, it declares a tv-specific operation, so, no, it’s not a correct implementation.

Comment: I agree with @mudasobwa. It's not very lucky example from real life because only TV by itself can execute own "on" command. Maybe replacing **TV** as receiver with some **InfraredSensor** is better example

Comment: @mudasobwa, you are right Command should be declared as interface(Command – declares an interface for executing an operation), but in general from Command pattern participants point of view example looks OK to me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the superclass `Command`. Just define those concrete commands. That's how dynamic programming languages doing things. They don't care about types. They only care about whether the objects have a required method.

Comment: Being dynamic for programming language does not mean “to allow code duplication and discard DRY principle.” If it’s implemented as above (which is wrong, see my answer for details,) `@tv` handling should be moved to the superclass, that therefore should remain.